# More NuGet hell

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget

Sorry - still scratching my head when it comes to NuGet. So I generated a bunch of packages and put them all on a network share. Things worked for a while, but then I started noticing that the versions that showed up in the NuGet Package Manager console didn't match what was on disk. (The version numbers didn't match what was on disk nor did the ID and description). Then I realized that there were additional .dlls needed in my package so I regenerated a new package with all of the necessary .dlls. In my testing I had been using versions 2.2, 2.4, 2.5 and 2.7, so I decided to start from scratch and created the new package as 2.0 with the title being "All Library Files". So I created a new .nuspec file in a new folder and *pack*ed it and then cleared out my network share that had all of the prior versions and then published it to the network share using *nuget init*. So I can go to the network share and all that's there is is a single folder with the name of my package and under that there are two folders: 2.0 and 2.1 (I created 2.1 later), but now when I open NuGet Package Manager at either the solution or the project level nothing shows up. I used Uninstall-Package to get rid of the initial ones and now whether I go to Installed Packages or Updates (or Online for that matter) I don't see anything. I expected to see the two new versions that I put in the folder. I've tried clearing the cache (both from the UI and the command line: **nuget locals all -clear**).

What could I possibly be doing wrong?

**UPDATE 8/11/17 2:19pm:**

I created a new folder on a local machine and copied all of my packages there and then added a new reference to it in the NuGet Package Manager and suddenly I can see all of my new packages. So somewhere it's gotta be caching that info. But now when I try to add one of my packages I get the error: **Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'lib/net40/** Library.dll. I've used file explorer to search all files on disk for the string "lib/net40" and nothing is found. AAAUUUUGGGHHHH!!!!

I've now resorted to deleting and re-getting the entire code-base (all 91,717 files) :-(.

Comment: Doing wrong? using a broke product like nuget for starters :)